# Interchanging limit and sum

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I'm looking at a probability question. Here we have $\lim_{m \to \infty}p_{i,j}(m) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^mf_{i,j}(r)p_{j,j}(m-r) =  \sum_{r=1}^mf_{i,j}(r)\lim_{m \to \infty} p_{j,j}(m-r)$.

The author justifies pulling the limit inside by applying dominated convergence theorem - since $f_{i,j}(r)p_{j,j}(m-r) \le f_{i,j}(r)$ and $\sum_{r=1}^\infty f_{i,j}(r) \le 1 < \infty$.

However, when I tried this question, I said that since all the entries are positive we can interchange limits and sums by Tonelli's theorem. I know this justification is correct in the following context:
$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty}E[X_n] = E[\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n]
$$

Does this also work for this question? I'm just curious to know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonelli's Theorem applies only to interchange of two integrals (or  a sum and an integral). It does not apply to interchange of limits and integrals. Non-negativity is no good enough for this.

Example: $\lim \int n\chi_{(0,\frac  1n)} =1 \neq  0= \int  \lim n\chi_{(0,\frac  1n)}$.